# How do I get the id of a clicked link and then style it in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, events, dom-events

How do I style a clicked link with CSS in JavaScript?

Here is my link:

```
<li><id="106" onClick="configurator(this)" href="#">10.6 &micro;</a><li>
```

I am trying to run a function called `configurator` and return the ID of the this link so I can set the CSS.

Help!  I am a JS newbie!

Here is my function:

```
function configurator(clicked) {
 
 document.getElementById(clicked);
 alert(clicked.name);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your onClick function is called as "configurator(this);", then you passed it the element itself, not the ID of the element.

```
function configurator(clicked) { 

// document.getElementById(clicked); // doesn't work because "clicked" is an element, not an ID
 clicked.style.fontWeight = "bold";
 // OR
 clicked.className = "boldClass";
 alert(clicked.name);   
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also just noticed that you are missing the "a" tag. It should be:

```
<li><a id="106" onClick="configurator(this)" href="#">10.6 &micro;</a><li>
```

Comment: Note that clicked.name will get you the "name" attribute of the html element. If you want the "id" attribute, use clicked.id.

Comment: Also, the way to use document.getElementById, would have been more like: clicked = document.getElementById("106"); since "106" is the ID of the element. The document.getElementById function will fetch the element itself based on that ID, and so the variable "clicked" would get that element itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can style an element like this:

```
element.style.color = 'white';
element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

To get the element which was clicked you could use the event:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
}
```

Example function from [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html).

**EDIT**: Other thing: It's bad practice to add onclick properties directly to the html. You could use [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) [java](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html)[script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

**EDIT 2**: A jQuery example.

```
$(function() // Alias for $(document).ready()
{
    $('li a').click(function()
    {
        $(this).css({
            color: 'red'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: OK, so if I do this through jQuery, is it like this for an anchor tag in a list item?  $("li a").click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});

Comment: With jQuery is everything more easy. I made you an example.

Comment: Thanks, joksnet.  You're always very helpful.

Comment: If I want to dynamically pass it an ID (of the particular link selected) how do that syntactically?

Comment: You could get the ID of the clicked `<a>` element by calling `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: How do I make the above script conditional so it clears all of the non-clicked elements (from previous clicks)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the above example, I've tried to clean it up as best I can. Here's code that I tested, that works by itself.  It's not pretty, but it works:

```
<li><a href="#" id="106" onClick="configurator(this)">10.6 &micro;</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function configurator(clicked) {
         alert(clicked.id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: perhaps you can explain better what style you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to achieve this.

This is completely untested but it should give you some direction.  Passing the whole css object came to me on the fly, you could alternatively omit this and hardcode the styles you are trying to change (but why would you wanna do that =P).

```
// Function to change the content of t2
function modifyStyle(styles) {
   //save element
   var that = this;
   for each (property in styles){
      that.style.property = styles[property];
   }  
}

// Function to add event listener anchor
function load() { 
  var el = document.getElementById("myAnchor"),
  cssObj = {
      background-color: 'black',
      font-size: 1.2em
  }
  //set the function call to an anonymous function that passes your css object
  el.addEventListener("click", 
                      function(){modifyStyle(cssObj)}, 
                      false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a id="106" onClick="configurator(this.id)" href="#">10.6 &micro;</a><li> 

function configurator(clicked) 
{  

 var elementClicked = document.getElementById(clicked); 
 //Set the styles using the ID element.clicked.style......
 alert(clicked);   
}
```

Use `document.getElementById(clicked);` to get the sent ID and then you can set the styles to this. You missed out the `a` tag, and you was passing the element name not ID.